# Calculate lowest common indivisible number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, double, decimal, price

I am making API calls to a shipping provider.

It returns the shipping price in the following format:
`"4250"` which is actually $42.50.

The API documentation says the following:
`Value in the lowest common indivisible unit of the currency. 42.50 CAD would be represented as 4250.`

How would I go about using Math functions in Javascript to make this display correctly? Obviously I don't want to charge $4250 for something that is really $42.50.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Example price from API response
const apiPrice = "4250";

// Convert to the actual currency value
const actualPrice = parseFloat(apiPrice) / 100;

// Format as currency (e.g., USD)
const formattedPrice = actualPrice.toLocaleString("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" });

console.log(formattedPrice);
```

You'd better not modify the numbers displayed, but let the interface return the data directly to you.